# Python find and count the items in a list of lists of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this list.

```
DESK_POLE = [[[100,100,1],[200,100,99],[300,100,99],[400,100,99],[500,100,0],[600,100,0],[700,100,0],[800,100,2]],
              [[100,200,0],[200,200,0],[300,200,0],[400,200,99],[500,200,0],[600,200,0],[700,200,0],[800,200,0]],
              [[100,300,0],[200,300,0],[300,300,0],[400,300,0],[500,300,0],[600,300,0],[700,300,0],[800,300,0]],
              [[100,400,0],[200,400,0],[300,400,0],[400,400,0],[500,400,0],[600,400,0],[700,400,0],[800,400,0]],
              [[100,500,0],[200,500,0],[300,500,0],[400,500,0],[500,500,0],[600,500,0],[700,500,0],[800,500,0]],
              [[100,600,0],[200,600,0],[300,600,0],[400,600,0],[500,600,0],[600,600,0],[700,600,0],[800,600,0]],
              [[100,700,0],[200,700,0],[300,700,0],[400,700,0],[500,700,0],[600,700,0],[700,700,0],[800,700,0]],
              [[100,800,2],[200,800,0],[300,800,0],[400,800,0],[500,800,0],[600,800,0],[700,800,0],[800,800,1]]]
```

How do I calculate how many times the number 99 is in this list?
How can I change the number 99 to 88, for example?
I want to avoid a two-loop solution.

Comment: May I know the reason for you avoiding a two loop method.

Comment: how about you code anything that works and then go for optimizing it instead of asking here to get a solution without any thinking or coding at all?

Comment: It seems to me that a two-loop solution is not Pythonic.

Comment: The eminent principle of any programming language is code which firs and foremost satisfies the requirements..  So start there

Answer (score 1):

While I am certain others will have an opinion of what is and is not "pythonic", I always recommend that solutions be implemented in the most easy to understand manner unless there are clear performance implications to the contrary.

In this instance, you want to avoid nested loops. Here is a potential way you might do that with a comprehension.

I would review it to make sure you feel it is actually simpler/clearer than more "traditional" `for` loops:

```
DESK_POLE = [
    [[100,100,1],[200,100,99],[300,100,99],[400,100,99],[500,100,0],[600,100,0],[700,100,0],[800,100,2]],
    [[100,200,0],[200,200,0],[300,200,0],[400,200,99],[500,200,0],[600,200,0],[700,200,0],[800,200,0]],
    [[100,300,0],[200,300,0],[300,300,0],[400,300,0],[500,300,0],[600,300,0],[700,300,0],[800,300,0]],
    [[100,400,0],[200,400,0],[300,400,0],[400,400,0],[500,400,0],[600,400,0],[700,400,0],[800,400,0]],
    [[100,500,0],[200,500,0],[300,500,0],[400,500,0],[500,500,0],[600,500,0],[700,500,0],[800,500,0]],
    [[100,600,0],[200,600,0],[300,600,0],[400,600,0],[500,600,0],[600,600,0],[700,600,0],[800,600,0]],
    [[100,700,0],[200,700,0],[300,700,0],[400,700,0],[500,700,0],[600,700,0],[700,700,0],[800,700,0]],
    [[100,800,2],[200,800,0],[300,800,0],[400,800,0],[500,800,0],[600,800,0],[700,800,0],[800,800,1]]
]

key = 99

count_of_key = sum(
    bit == key
    for row in DESK_POLE
    for cell in row
    for bit in cell
)

print(count_of_key)
```

This gives you back:

```
4
```

While this might avoid looping in *your* code, almost certainly there is looping in the background.

A different approach might be to regex, but I think that would be "unsavory".

Comment: The `for` loops in that comprehension are not exactly hidden :-) Anyway, I'd go with `sum(bit == key for row in DESK_POLE for cell in row for bit in cell)` as slightly idiomatic. (`sum(boolean iterator)` is why `count` isn't needed in Python).

Comment: @rici That seems like a perfectly reasonable change and one that removes a like of cruft so I'm happy to integrate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to make the list flat using `chain.from_iterable()`, and use the `list.count()` method:

```py
from itertools import chain

flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(DESK_POLE)))
print(flat_list.count(99))
```

To change every 99 to 88, using `chain.from_iterable` with `enumerate()` works.

```py
import itertools

flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(DESK_POLE)))

for index, _ in enumerate(flat_list):
    if flat_list[index] == 99:
        flat_list[index] = 88

print(flat_list)
```